# How to create a wildcard text index in mongoDB using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I know wildcard text index in mongoDB can be created in shell using:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

And to create a index in pymongo:

```
db[COLLECTION].create_index(index_name, index)
```

I don't know how to create a wildcard index in pymongo. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Signature: **db.a.create_index(keys, **kwargs)**
>
> [Docstring:
>   Creates an index on this collection](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.1/pymongo/collection.py#L1658).
>
> Takes either a single key or a list of (key, direction) pairs.
>   The key(s) must be an instance of :class:`basestring`
>   (:class:`str` in python 3), and the direction(s) must be one of
>   (:data:`~pymongo.ASCENDING`, :data:`~pymongo.DESCENDING`,
>   :data:`~pymongo.GEO2D`, :data:`~pymongo.GEOHAYSTACK`,
>   :data:`~pymongo.GEOSPHERE`, :data:`~pymongo.HASHED`,
>   :data:`~pymongo.TEXT`).

To create a text index on all fields, we just
use a list of a single tuple containing field and direction as argument:

```
import pymongo

db.collection.create_index([("$**", pymongo.TEXT)])

print(list(db.collection.list_indexes()))
```